# Probability that common part of two line segments is less than a given number

Tags: calculus, probability

On a straight line segment  $AB$ of length $a+b$, two segments $PQ,P'Q'$ of lengths $a,b$ respectively are measured at random.

Then if $c$ is less than $a$ or $b$ ,the chance that common part of $PQ,P'Q'$ is less than $c$ is -----

Let us take point $ A$ to be the origin,and point $B$ to be $a+b$.
Then Q be y and P' be x.so the required probability should be

$$\frac{\int_{a}^{a+b} \int_{y-c}^y dxdy}{ \int_{a}^{a+b} \int_{0}^a dxdy}$$

However I am not getting the correct answer. Please help me in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) $$\left|PQ \cup P'Q'\right|=|PQ|+|P'Q'|-\left|PQ \cap P'Q'\right|=a+b-|PQ \cap P'Q'|$$ we obtain $$\left|PQ \cap P'Q'\right|=a+b-\left|PQ \cup P'Q'\right|$$

Now $$\left|PQ \cap P'Q'\right| < c\Leftrightarrow a+b-\left|PQ \cup P'Q'\right| < c \Leftrightarrow  a+b-c<\left|PQ \cup P'Q'\right| \leq AB=a+b$$ 
Using geometrical probability, this is
$$P\left(\left|PQ \cap P'Q'\right| < c\right)=1-\frac{c}{a+b}$$

Comment: This is really nice if you set $a=b=c$. It shows that there's a 50/50 chance that two intervals will completely overlap.

Comment: Yes, interesting indeed.